# What is this tree with red seeds in france

Tags: identification, trees

On a field trip in Strasbourg france I noticed this tree.  What is it?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi kevinsky! For [identification](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info) questions, we need as many details as possible! Can you get a clearer picture of this flower, a picture of the whole tree and more leaves? Are those seedpods with one red seed in each? Are the stems brown or pink? How tall was it? Did you see it in a yard, or someplace else? What are your average temperatures, or growing zone? Every detail will help us get you the right identification. Edit the information right into your question for all to see! Thanks!

Comment: @Sue yes, I have more photos but they are too large to post.  As I am travelling l will post them when possible.  I will also have a meta comment on how hard it is to post a cellphone photo

Comment: Couldn’t ping you in [chat]...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The picture, while very pretty, is not easy to identify this tree from.

But I did notice the automatically generated "related questions" column on the right of this web page is suggesting "Is this an Ailanthus tree?" as a formerly asked, related question.

Well I don't know how that "artificial intelligence" ever figured it out, but since it did come up, yes, I think it might very well be an Ailanthus (or Tree-of-Heaven, or Paradise-Tree = alternative names). Was it very tall, and did it give off a mild not-very-nice smell? If you rub their leaves, they smell even worse, like peanut butter mixed with cat-kibble. See if the pictures you get from searching Ailanthus look familiar to you.

Comment: Yes, it is Ailanthus altissima or tree of heaven. Good answer!

Comment: And it is an high invasive species. Often in black lists: as you see from the picture, it likes to grow on urbanized places, but so the root tend to ruins pavements (it makes a lot of seedling (you see on the picture), which grows from every tiny holes on pavements.

Comment: Yes, Mr. Catenazzi, it is awful.